# increase pixel size in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, pixel

As I said I have 2D matrix 68 per 68 and I want to make a heat map from it.
Each value in the matrix should be displayed as a separate cell. Every fourth cell should be labelled as "XXX\n715" 0, "XXX\n718" 3 and so on...

This is my plot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiipsn5mhmbnb5b/TEST.png?dl=0

Data used to produce this plot can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/izrfbm157q1tedj/matrix.dat?dl=0

At present, I can see two problems with my plot:

1.) Cells are too small. Therefore, the plot is hard to read.
    I want to increase size of a cell 2 times.
    If I understand correctly, each pixel corresponds to one value?
    If so, I would like to increase size of a pixel. That's way I was thinking
    about drawing a grid size of 68*2/68*2, so that each value in my matrix will 
    be displayed in a 2-pixel/2-pixel-square box (cell).

2.) Values are outside cells's borders.
   I had the same problem with smaller 2D arrays and I fixed it by trying 
   different resolutions (terminal size). I have been trying to apply a discussed 
   solution for the 68x68 matrix, but it did not work for me.

I tested many different scripts and I am stuck on these problems.

Thank you.

Code below:

```
  set terminal png transparent truecolor nocrop enhanced size 800,800 font    
  "arial bold,8” 
  set output 'TEST.png'
  set size ratio 1
  set palette rgbformulae -21,-22,-23
  # drawing grid 
  set x2tics 1 format '' scale 0,0.001
  set y2tics 1 format '' scale 0,0.001
  set mx2tics 2
  set my2tics 2

 # labels
 set xtics 3 out nomirror
 set ytics 3 out nomirror
 set grid front mx2tics my2tics lw 0.5 lt 1 lc rgb 'black'
 set xrange[-0.5:67.5]
 set yrange[-0.5:67.5]
 set x2range[-0.5:67.5]
 set y2range[-0.5:67.5]
 set xtics add ("XXX\n715" 0, "XXX\n718" 3)
 set ytics add ("XXX\n715" 0, "XXX\n718" 3)
 plot "matrix.dat" matrix w image noti
```

Comment: Why do you need this? If its only about the axis labelling, then use `set autoscale xfix; set autoscale yfix; plot "contact_max_average_np2.dat" matrix using ($1*4):($2*4):3 with image` (I prefer `plot` for image heatmaps instead of `splot`)

Comment: Hi, I tried to be more precise. Any suggestions?